# How to display chinese names in excel sheet?

Tags: excel

I have a database that contains both English and Chinese names, when importing the CSV file It is unable to display Chinese characters(names). I have tried importing from data and Tab delimited->UTF-8->Tab Delimited. It worked but the columns or shifting and overlapping. Is there any other software that displays both Chinese and English characters in the large data Excel sheet or any solution to fix this in Microsoft excel 2007 is much appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/27347804-How-To-Import-a-Unicode-CSV-to-Excel) looks promising

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UTF-8 character setting for the column(s) which has Chinese characters.